# Is there something to be said for putting the "default" case of a switch statement first?

Tags: coding-style, switch-statement

Like:

```
switch (value) {
default:
    something_common()
case 1:
    niche_case()
...
}
```

etcetera.

`if-else` statements require an "if" first and an "else" last, but `switch` statements are more flexible in their ordering. I think it's important to know what will happen "normally", which `default` indicates.

Comment: Somewhat related is [Switch statement: must default be the last case?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3110088/3235496) (especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/3110336/3235496). Although unusual, it isn't unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the `default` statement first will work technically, but is a very unusual idiom. IMHO that's because what you scetched above is not the typical "use case" for a `switch/default` block. It is much more common to use the `default` branch similar to an `else` statement, like

```
switch (value) {
case 1:
    potential_case1()
case 2:
    potential_case2()
case 3:
    potential_case3()
default:
    remaining_cases()
...
}
```

(for the sake of brevity, I left out the `break` statements intentionally).

In fact, the keyword `default` might give you a different association, but don't forget these terms were defined in the C language several decades ago and inherited by lots of other languages like C++, JavaScript, Java, C# or PHP - noone will change that now for historical reasons and reasons of backwards compatibility.

In some other languages, where the language creators did not follow a "similar control-of-flow terms as in C" goal, the `default` section is named in a manner which expresses the intention of beeing an "else" branch more clearly, like in VB.NET, where it is called `Case Else`, or `Perl`, where indeed the term `else` is used.

Comment: Wait. Are you saying all the switch values are compared and default only called when none match? I thought each was evaluated top to bottom untill a break was hit? In which case putting default.. break; at the top would prevent any othrr case being called

Comment: @ewan that's what I thought too. Especially with the ones with fallthrough behaviour like C. AFAIK in any other language you still have a short-circuiting feature that can be optimised by putting any massivly more frecuent cases at the front…

Comment: @Ewan: how can a "default" case be evaluated except by evaluating all the other cases? In the question's example, how can we know we have a "default" case without evaluation whether "value" equals "1"? Or, the other way around, if everything is evaluated as a default case, we would _never_ end up in the case 1: branch!

Comment: just checked the (c#) spec and doc is right (as usual) I always think of it working the old c++ way with (optional) breaks and default as a catch all. Although im not even sure that is right for c++ now!!

Comment: @Ewan: "although im not even sure that is right for c++" - it is. Language designers of the mainstream languages typically don't start to change basic control-of-flow semantics in an incompatible manner, not for a really, really good reason.